# Journey builder: what is "Email Attributes > Email Addresses"

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

Can anyone help me understand this mysterious concept!

As we can see the below options within **Use email attribute from Contacts**

[image: Email Attributes > Email Addresses]

I could NOT find this "Email Attributes > Email Addresses" neither in ATTRIBUTE GROUP nor in POPULATIONS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the SYSTEM_DATA Attribute Group in the DataDesigner.

[image]

When you watch the All-Subscriber-Table inside marketing cloud this is the stuff where this data refers to. It is the email address that is attached to the subscriber in the marketing cloud. All e-mails where you only include a subscriberkey to send an email will result to send in this direction (normal send proccesses etc.).

These email-adresses can only be changed via import-file processes or some manual tasks like changing it in the subscriber search (and i believe some rest or soap calls, but not sure on the that one).

Comment: Thanks that was a great clear and crisp explanation @Johannes Schapdick