# Is email required in a DE to send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

This may be a dumb question but is an email address required in a DE to send? For example, the subscriber key is in the DE and that would relate to the contact but there is no email address present in the DE. This would be for journey builder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget to mark Rachid's answer as accepted, of it was useful to you

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. No, it is not required.

You can select the email address to be used from the Journey Settings of your Journey.

> Do you want your journey to always send to the email address
> associated with each contact, or can that email address change during
> the journey? If the email address can change, choose to identify and
> use an email attribute from Contacts.
>
> - Select **Use email attribute from Contacts**. If the email address can change, as in a journey with a long duration, choose to use the
>   email attribute associated with Contacts.
> - Select **Use email attribute from Entry Source**. If a contact’s email address is unlikely to change or a journey doesn’t allow
>   re-entry, use the email for the contact at entry.
>
> The same principles apply to the mobile number you select as default.

Lukas note: One should keep in mind, that this can't be the first email sent to this particular subscriber key, as the person in this point will not be found within All Subscribers/All Contacts

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_settings.htm&type=5

For more information about **"Email Attributes > Email Addresses"**, check out Johannes's answer here: [Journey builder: what is "Email Attributes > Email Addresses"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287150/journey-builder-what-is-email-attributes-email-addresses)

Comment: One should keep in mind, that this can't be the first email sent to this particular subscriber key, as the person in this point will not be found within All Subscribers/All Contacts

Comment: Yeah sure, I've assumed he already imported the contact since he said in the question: "the subscriber key is in the DE and that would relate to the contact". But I'm adding it to the answer to remove any doubts.. Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick answer. Does this work the same in email studio sending single sends?

Comment: There is more to it than this. Check out Lukas's detailed answer here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261592/subscriber-key-related-to-multiple-emails/261602#261602